# C++ static constexpr class member with complex class linking issues

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, static, constexpr

I have the following :

Header file:

```
class CU
{
  const char *u;
public:
  constexpr CU (const char *u) :u(u) {}
  constexpr const char *c_str () const { return u; } ;
  constexpr operator const char *  () const { return u; } ;
};

void test2 (const CU & r) ;

class S
{
public:
  static constexpr CU u = CU("foo"); // linker error
  /*
    when I use the u in the normal constructor in a separate file I get a linker error
  */
  S();     
};
```

Source file :

```
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void test2 (const CU & r) 
{
  std::cerr << r;
}

S::S() 
{
  test2(S::u);
}

int main () {
  S a;  
}
```

Output from the compiler :

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 test.cpp test.hpp
/tmp/cceBFmJM.o: In function S::S():
test.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to S::u
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

See the bugzilla report here :
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67155

Comment: I don't see a definition for `S::u`. Making it `constexpr` doesn't mean that the declaration is a definition.

Comment: The object is defined inline in the header. If used in the header it works, if it is a c string it works, see the code here https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gcc-plugin-cpp-template/tree/constexpr/testcase

Comment: adding this to the c file solved the problem. constexpr CU S::u;

Comment: here is the best description of the problem https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition thanks to Jonathan Wakely (@redi )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add this to the source file :

constexpr CU S::u;

Thanks @chris and @Drew Dormann.